# How do I get object type using dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am doing a homework, and I am stuck in something:
I've done everything, but there is a function in specific class, that I didn't know how to implement.
I have a class named A let's say, and two classes that inherit from A, let's call them B and C.
So basically main class is A, and inherit classes are B and C, and I have a set of elements for these types (set of pointers for A), `set<A*>` , and have enum that identifies each class, like that: `enum { A , B ,C};`

the function has to filter the set and return a set with the type given from the enum, like:

`set<A*> MainClass::getByType(Type type) const {
}`

the thing is that we are not allowed to use the keyword `typeid`, but instead we have to use `dynamic_cast`, in order to determine the type.

my question is:
when I pass on each element in the `set<A*>`, how am I supposed to know what type is that element (A or B or C), using `dynamic_cast` ?

I don't get it,
please help me, it's the final thing in the homework and I'm stuck,
Thank you in advance <3

Comment: Just use `switch` on `enum` and try to `dynamic_vast` to proper type.

Comment: You cast to `B*`: if you get a non-NULL pointer back, it's a `B`. Otherwise, you cast to `C*`, and if you get a non-NULL pointer back, it's a `C`. Otherwse, it's an `A`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you did not read the question, OP does not need to determine actual type, rather to filter by criteria defined by enum

Comment: @Slava Quoth the OP: *"my question is: when I pass on each element in the set<A*>, how am I supposed to know what type is that element (A or B or C), using `dynamic_cast` ?"* I believe I've answered the question as explicitly stated.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik there is no reason to hide behind formality, OP just does not know how to say what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your task you do not need to know what class is particular instance belongs to but filter pointers that point to particular class. So define a function, that checks if pointer is proper class using switch:

```
bool checkType( A *ptr, Type type )
{
    switch( type ) {
       case typeB: return dynamic_cast<B*>( ptr );
       // check for other types here
       ...
       default: throw std::runtime_error( "this type not supported" );
    }
}
```

then use [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to filter types that you need and put them in result set or just use range loop. If it is not clear how this code works, checking line can be written more explicit way:

```
   case typeB: return dynamic_cast<B*>( ptr ) != nullptr;
```

Comment: It’s probably worth pointing out *how* this works, because that isn’t clear from the quoted code. The key insight is that if `dynamic_cast` fails (because the object isn’t of the correct type), it [returns a null pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). Converting a pointer to a `bool` checks whether or not it’s null, so this function will return `true` iff the pointer is non-null, so the cast succeeded.

Comment: if type is determined, ```static_cast``` can be used

Comment: @user5821508 type is not determined, the whole point of this function to check if pointer is proper type as defined by enum.

Comment: @Slava i see. this check may do work also ```case typeB: return typeid (*ptr).hash_code() == typeid(B).hash_code()```

Comment: @user5821508 OP specially mentioned that `typeid` is not allowed.